# When saving PDF (manually and also by script), some cells with values appear empty (Google Sheets)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Updating the question, the problem I could see was not with the script but directly with the spreadsheet.

I tried to save the PDF manually and some images still not showing up.

In Spreadsheet File Online:

[image]

PDF Save Manually:

[image]

The curious fact is that until yesterday this was not happening.

Link to Spreadsheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tg3p3q0gPKWPoeoxbFTE5tJgrU5dQnGa6ok2LcsXNns/edit#gid=45463727&range=A1

Obs.: I removed all other pages from the spreadsheet, also removed the formulas and left this page to share, with values only. Still the error still persists when I create a pdf

Comment: Some one has probably experienced the  same issue.  But fortunately for them they had a script in front them that  they could work with. We don't.

Comment: @Cooper Cooper, in my questions I always put scripts and etc. The problem is that it has a lot of private data, before I had to edit it entirely to send it, I tried to ask to see if there is a general answer to this problem. But if it doesn't work out with the tip I got from the other member, I'll post the script.

Comment: @Cooper The attempt did not work, I added the full script and also an example of what is happening.

Comment: When the Spreadsheet shown at `IN SPREADSHEET:` is manually exported as a PDF file, if the PDF file of the same result with the Spreadsheet could be got, for example, how about putting `Utilities.sleep(10000)` before and/or after `SpreadsheetApp.flush()`? Because I thought that in your script, `IMPORTHTML` and `IMPORTXML` are put to the cells and the values from their functions might not be loaded completely when the Spreadsheet is exported as the PDF. But I'm not sure whether this is the direct reason of your issue. So when this didn't resolve your issue, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike I found that really, even saving manually without script the error still persists. So the problem is not really in the script but in the spreadsheet.

The curious fact is that until yesterday this was not happening.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Can you provide a sample Spreadsheet for replicating the issue? I would like to confirm it. Of course, please remove your personal information.

Comment: @Tanaike Thanks for support, sample spreadsheet (without formulas), with values only. Already shared, updated question.

Comment: Thank you for adding the information. When I open your shared Spreadsheet, I noticed very long loading time. Unfortunately, although I'm waiting for more than 15 minutes, the loading is still not completed. Although from such situation, I cannot confirm the direct reason of your issue, I thought that this long loading might be one of reasons of your issue. For example, in your case, how about retrieving all values using only Google Apps Script without using the formulas of `IMPORTHTML` and `IMPORTXML`?

Comment: @Tanaike When it open spreadsheet, immediately click on the ```Sheet29``` page that the spreadsheet will load fully. Then when loading, enter the Squads page that will load very fast.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I could confirm the issue. It was found that when the shared Spreadsheet is manually exported it 3 times as PDF file, the file sizes were different. Those were 1,695,404, 1,704,928 and 1,704,789 bytes. And the unshown images were different for 3 PDF files. On the other hand, it was found that when the Spreadsheet was exported as HTML, all images were included. From this result, it is considered that the Spreadsheet has the information of all images. From above situation, how about reporting your issue to [the issue tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker)?

Comment: @Tanaike I did not know this tool, I will do it now. I hope Google can solve this problem quickly. Too bad trying to save the file and come up with flaws in images. Anyway, thank you so much for the time you spent helping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling `SpreadsheetApp.flush();` on the line before you create the PDF. This will force an update of all calculations before creating the PDF.

If this doesn't work then you'll need to post your script and some samples so we can try to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will test this now and any thing I update the question, the script has a lot of private data, so I tried to ask a general question because there could be a general answer like the one you gave me.

Comment: James D, Unfortunately I added one more flush as you requested, even though there was one before the PDF was created. But it still happens all the same. I added the full script and also an example of what is going on.